# Redirect JSF ajax request to an URL with request parameters in a servlet filter

Tags: ajax, xml, jsf-2, servlet-filters, http-request-parameters

I am using JSF2.2 and have servlet filter configured. Part of the code in Filter that work:

```java
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
if (userSession == null) {

    redirectURLRegular = response.encodeRedirectURL("../login.xhtml?param1=noSession");
    redirectURLAjax = response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath()
                + "/faces/login.xhtml?param1=noSession");

else{
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    return;

if (isAJAXRequest(request)) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
            <partial-response><redirect url=\"").append(redirectURLAjax)
                .append("\"></redirect></partial-response>");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/xml");

        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println(sb.toString());
        pw.flush();

    } else { 
        response.sendRedirect(redirectURLRegular);
    }
```

If session is null redirect - both regular and AJAX happens. In next page (login.xhtml, requestScoped) I can get parameter value (param1) in bean via

```java
@ManagedProperty("#{param.param1}")
private String param1;
```

If I add second param `"../login.xhtml?param1=noSession&param2=val2"` - regular requests work (redirect happens and see both params) but AJAX request dose not work(no redirect, nothing happens). Here is Firebug report:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: moz-nullprincipal:{4584d37a-e799-43db-8379-b0451edca95c} Line Number 1, Column 120:

..."/admin/faces/login.xhtml?param1=noSession&param2=val2"></redirect></partial-r...
...-------------------------------------------------^
```

How is this caused and how can we set multiple parameters in filter for AJAX calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` is a special character in XML representing the start of an [entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) like `&amp;`, `&lt;`, etc. The XML parser is implicitly looking for the name (`amp`, `lt`, etc) and the ending `;`. However, you wasn't using it as such and hence the webbrowser's XML parser felt over it when it unexpectedly encountered an `=`, making it non-[well-formed XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document).

You need to escape the XML special character `&` into the entity `&amp;`.

```java
redirectURLAjax = response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath()
            + "/faces/login.xhtml?param1=noSession&amp;param2=val2");
```